# How Can I generate a static url a file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to generate a static URL based on a few parameters.
The page serve the file for downloading is called CertificateDownload.aspx ,I am generating the download link in Report.aspx.These 2 files reside on the same physical folder.I do not like the replace method ,but I could not think of another way of doing it.
How can I improve my code or what is a better way of doing it.

I need the absolute url to be displayed as text in the web browser.

`Dim downLoadUrl As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString.Replace("Report.aspx",     "CertificateDownload.aspx") + "?CertificateID=" + CertificateName`

```
HyperLinkDownloadLink.Visible = True
HyperLinkDownloadLink.Text = downLoadUrl
HyperLinkDownloadLink.NavigateUrl = downLoadUrl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it cleanly with UriBuilder.  Some people might say it's overkill, but it makes the intent of the code very clear and it's easier to program and maintain, and less error-prone.

```
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
    uriBuilder.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(uriBuilder.Path) + "/CertificateDownload.aspx";
    uriBuilder.Query = "CertificateID=" + CertificateName;
    var downloadUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using a relative url?

```
downLoadUrl = "CertificateDownload.aspx?CertificateID=" + CertificateName
```

Much simpler.

Comment: I need the absolute url to be displayed as text in the web browser,this not what I need

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.MapPath(string.format("CertificateDownload.aspx?CertificateID={0}", CertificateName))
```

Comment: MapPath returns a physical path for the specified relative url.  It doesn't return a URL.  It will give very different results than the Url.ToString().Replace() call in the original.

Comment: Why do you need to absolute URL anyway? You said you want the show the links in the Report.aspx. Therefore you don't need absolute URLs here, because when you use a hyperlink mapped with Request.MapPath you will see the absolute URL as it will be displayed in the browser

Comment: That's the requirement, I need the absolute url to be displayed as text in the web browser.

Comment: This not what I need ,it will map to a physical path.